# Solving a category partition task in producing tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, functional-testing, black-box, black-box-testing

I am struggling with a problem for a long time and I just cannot manage to find the right way to solve a category partition problem. I would be very happy and grateful if someone manage to explain how to proceed.
OK... here is the sample:

```
Parameters!
Pattern!
 Size:!
 empty [property Empty]!
 single character [property NonEmpty]
 many character [property NonEmpty]
 too long [property NonEmpty]

 Quoting:
 quoted [property quoted]
 not quoted [if NonEmpty]
 improperly quoted [if NonEmpty]

 Embedded blanks:
 no blanks [if NonEmpty]
 one blank [if NonEmpty and Quoted]
 several blanks [if NonEmpty and Quoted]


 Embedded quotes:
 no quotes [if NonEmpty]
 one quote [if NonEmpty and Quoted]
 several quotes [if NonEmpty and Quoted]

 File name:
 good
 no ﬁle
 omitted

Environment
 Number of occurrences:


 none [if NonEmpty]
 exactly one [if NonEmpty][property Match]
 more than one [if NonEmpty][property Match]

 Pattern occurrences on target line!
 one [if Match]!
 more than one [if Match]
```

The answer is supposed to be 678, but I just can't manage to get it ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your problem. You haven't said what it is that's supposed to have the answer '678'? Are you referring to the total number of test frames this configuration would produce? Please clarify your question.